# Advantages of sending API authentication_token via headers vs. parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise

This [tutorial](http://www.soryy.com/blog/2014/apis-with-devise/)  for building API's with Devise recommends using headers to send over the login email and API token vs. embeding them as URL parameters.

> Rather than sending the data over parameters, we're expecting the client application to send it via two headers: "X-API-EMAIL" and "X-API-TOKEN"; this cleans up the endpoint URIs.

Can someone elaborate on what it means to "clean up" theWhat are the the advantages of requiring authentication via headers vs. having the client embed them as parameters in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think by "clean up" they just mean that the URLs are tidier and only contain information about the resource being requested/updated/...

It's common to use this approach -- it can be argued that it's conceptually nicer to keep what you are requesting somewhat separate from the details of your credentials for making the request.  The "Authorization" HTTP header is a standard one to use for credentials (e.g. HTTP Basic Auth http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side, AWS API http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader and many more).

It also removes the possibility of clashes between your credential parameters and other parameters.  For a trivial example, imagine you use `password` for your credential password and also want a normal parameter called `password` for a particular API call (when you're updating another user perhaps).  You can't have that - one of them has to be named differently.  Ok, you can easily do that, but it's a little artificial, and if you instead supply the password for the credentials in the Authorization header, you are free to have a parameter called `password` which relates to the actual request you are making (e.g. the new password you're setting for some other user).